# style links, but text links only. is there a way?

Tags: css, hyperlink, hover

i'm having a bad day, and seems i am unable to find the right workaround to my issue.

let's keep it simple: i have my nice css for links, but i want to apply at text links only, so no images or divs or anything. just text.

my code:

```
a {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    color: #ffffff;
}

a:after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    transform: scaleX(0);
    height: 2px;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    transform-origin: bottom right;
    transition: transform 0.25s ease-out;
}

a:hover:after {
    transform: scaleX(1);
    transform-origin: bottom left;
}
```

every link got that fancy animation, but i want it applied only on text links. now, every image linked to something got the underline thing, of course. so, my question is:

is there a way to say 'only text links, not everything'? i need something working globally, without the need to create new classes for every element like images or divs, for example. just a nice little thing like:

```
a:text {
color: #ffffff;
}
```

this is because a lot of people will work on contents without access to the code, they will not be able to add classes to anything. if they put an image in a page, they cannot write nowhere things like 'this image is a link but i need to hide the underline stuff', this thing needs to be set up and forgot for everyone except two people who can look at the css.

i've found only bad solutions like 'create a class with a custom hover effect showing nothing' but this wold be my least preferred way because i will need to create custom classes for every element that can be a link someday.

hope you can help, thanks

Answer (score 0):

A bit late to the party, but with the introduction of the [:has selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:has) you could style links without images (and/or whatever else you want to exclude) with something like this:

```css
a:not(:has(img,div)) {
  /* styling for links not containing <img> or <div> */
  /* e.g. a beautiful red outline for demonstrational purposes */
  outline: 6px solid red;
}
```

```html
<a href="#"><img src="https://picsum.photos/140" /></a><br/>
<a href="#">This link has only text</a><br/>
<a href="#"><div>This link has a div in it and will not be targeted</div></a>
```

<strike>**Note**: As of this writing, **this will not work in Firefox**. The :has selector is supported in all other major browsers, so hopefully Firefox will follow soon.</strike>

**Edit**: The :has selector is now [supported by all major browsers](https://caniuse.com/?search=%3Ahas).

Comment: Support by all major browsers, if you can guarantee everyone looking at your site in Firefox has upgraded to FF120, which is not available on the ESR update channel that most people use.

Answer (score -1):

Unfortunately, HTML is not a conditional language.

You could make sure that only `a href` tags that have a paragraph will work with the css

```
a p{}
```

So instead of a global link tag css, you could try to set different css for img tags / other tags

```
a img {}
```

Comment: the odd thing is you can actually say 'a img' but not 'a text'

Comment: generally Text = p tag

Comment: That is not at all a good assumption. You generally don't get <p> tags inside <a> tags, that would be very unusual.